# How can I create object with any fields and some specific fields/methods in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript, I can implement this by:

```js
var obj = {
  get(k) {
    return this[k] || '';
  },
  set(k, v) {
    this[k] = v;
    return this;
  }
};
obj.set('a', 'A');
obj.get('a'); // return 'A';
```

However it seems that I can not do the same thing in typescript ?

```
class MyObj {
  [name: string]: string;

  public get(k: string): string {
    return this[k] || '';
  }
}
```

tsc will throw `Property 'get' of type '(k: string) => string' is not assignable to string index type 'string'`.

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether are you looking for this

```
class MyObj {
  [name: string]: object;

  public get(k: string): object | string{
    return this[k] || '';
  }

   public set(k: string, v: any): this  {  
    this[k] = v
    return this;
  }
}

const obj = new MyObj()

console.log(obj.set('a','b').get('a'))
```

Comment: You changed types.

Comment: method cant be added to string datatypes hence i had to change the type

Comment: Maybe this is the only way to fix my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that this Class can have any variable name and one of them can be `get` but Typescript is confused because this get function has different type of what you declared, to keep code more tidy I would keep all variables in a private variable like:

```
class MyObj {
  variables: { [name: string]: string };

  public get(k: string): string {
    return this.variables[k] || "";
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this will work, but I just don't like the wrapper `variables`.